# Should I use DbContext alone or DbSet when performing CRUD in ASP.NET Core using EF Core

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

To my knowledge you can perform CRUD using both DdbContext alone, or the DbSet itself (on top of DbContext). Is one way better than the other?

## *Create:*

*Dbset:*

```
<DBCONTEXT>.<DBSET>.Add(Object);
<DBCONTEXT>.SaveChanges();
```

*DbContext Only:*

```
<DBCONTEXT>.Add(Object);
<DBCONTEXT>.SaveChanges();
```

---

## *Read:*

*DbSet:*

```
<DBCONTEXT>.<DBSET>.Find(Object.ID);
```

*DbContext Only:*

```
<DBCONTEXT>.Find(<Type>, Object.ID);
```

---

## *Update:*

*DbContext Only:*

```
<DBCONTEXT>.Update(Object);
<DBCONTEXT>.SaveChanges();
```

---

## *Delete:*

*DbSet:*

```
<DBCONTEXT>.<DBSET>.Remove(Object);
<DBCONTEXT>.SaveChanges();
```

*DbContext Only:*

```
<DBCONTEXT>.Remove(Object);
<DBCONTEXT>.SaveChanges();
```

Answer (score 1):

I've found my anwser, it seems they do the exact same thing, for example, the dbset.Add() simply calls dbcontext.Add().

```
public override EntityEntry<TEntity> Add(TEntity entity)
            => _context.Add(entity);
```

[DbSet Code on Github](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/blob/master/src/EFCore/Internal/InternalDbSet.cs)

Comment: Which version do you prefer and why? I'm curious because my team asked me for recommendation and I want to get "more eyes" on the decision regarding code style.